# Why does this result of a binary operator need an appropriate lifetime?

Tags: rust

This is related to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852367/how-can-i-require-that-a-reference-to-a-generic-type-can-be-compared-for-equalit) on making a modular exponentiation method generic. I've now arrived at the following code:

```
fn powm<T>(fbase: &T, exponent: &T, modulus: &T) -> T
where
    T: Mul<T, Output = T>
        + From<u8>
        + PartialEq<T>
        + Rem<T, Output = T>
        + Copy
        + for<'a> Rem<&'a T, Output = T>
        + Clone
        + PartialOrd<T>
        + ShrAssign<T>,
    for<'a> &'a T: PartialEq<T> + Rem<&'a T, Output = T>,
{
    if modulus == T::from(1) {
        T::from(0)
    } else {
        let mut result = T::from(1);
        let mut base = fbase % modulus;
        let mut exp = exponent.clone();
        while exp > T::from(0) {
            if exp % T::from(2) == T::from(1) {
                result = (result * base) % modulus;
            }
            exp >>= T::from(1);
            base = (base * base) % modulus;
        }
        result
    }
}
```

It is my understanding that by defining the trait bound `where for<'a> &'a T: Rem<&'a T, Output=T>` that it is understood that I can use the modulo operator `%` on two operands of type `&'a T`, and the result will be of type `T`. However, I get the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:20:30
   |
20 |         let mut base = fbase % modulus;
   |                              ^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #3 defined on the function body at 3:1...
  --> src/main.rs:3:1
   |
3  | / fn powm<T>(fbase: &T, exponent: &T, modulus: &T) -> T
4  | | where
5  | |     T: Mul<T, Output = T>
6  | |         + From<u8>
...  |
30 | |     }
31 | | }
   | |_^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:20:32
   |
20 |         let mut base = fbase % modulus;
   |                                ^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the function body at 3:1...
  --> src/main.rs:3:1
   |
3  | / fn powm<T>(fbase: &T, exponent: &T, modulus: &T) -> T
4  | | where
5  | |     T: Mul<T, Output = T>
6  | |         + From<u8>
...  |
30 | |     }
31 | | }
   | |_^
note: ...so that types are compatible (expected std::ops::Rem, found std::ops::Rem<&T>)
  --> src/main.rs:20:30
   |
20 |         let mut base = fbase % modulus;
   |                              ^
```

The code does work if I replace the line in question by

```
let mut base = fbase.clone() % modulus;
```

I don't see why I would need to clone in the first place if I can use the modulo operator already to return a "fresh" element of type `T`. Do I need to modify my trait bounds instead? Why does this go wrong?

Comment: FWIW, I'd probably just [avoid taking references at all](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=9889ac1244f40e9bb180c6292895401c&version=stable).

Answer (score 3):

When programming, it's very useful to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](/help/mcve). This allows you to ignore irrelevant details and focus on the core of the problem.

As one example, your entire blob of code can be reduced down to:

```
use std::ops::Rem;

fn powm<T>(fbase: &T, modulus: &T)
where
    for<'a> &'a T: Rem<&'a T, Output = T>,
{
    fbase % modulus;
}

fn main() {}
```

Once you have a MCVE, you can make permutations to it to explore. For example, we can remove [the lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision):

```
fn powm<'a, 'b, T>(fbase: &'a T, modulus: &'b T)
where
    for<'x> &'x T: Rem<&'x T, Output = T>,
{
    fbase % modulus;
}
```

Now we start to see something: what is the relation between all three lifetimes? Well, there isn't one, really. What happens if we make one?

- If we say that the input references can be unified to the same
  lifetime, it works:

  ```
  fn powm<'a, T>(fbase: &'a T, modulus: &'a T)
  ```
- If we say that `'b` outlives `'a`, it works:

  ```
  fn powm<'a, 'b: 'a, T>(fbase: &'a T, modulus: &'b T)
  ```
- If we say that we can have two different lifetimes in the operator, it works:

  ```
  for<'x, 'y> &'x T: Rem<&'y T, Output = T>,
  ```

What about if we poke at the call site?

- If we directly call the `Rem::rem` method, it works:

  ```
  Rem::rem(fbase, modulus);
  ```
- If we dereference and re-reference, it works:

  ```
  &*fbase % &*modulus;
  ```

I don't know *exactly* why the original doesn't work — <s>conceptually both the input references should be able to be unified to one lifetime. It's possible that there's a piece of inference that either cannot or isn't happening, but I'm not aware of it.</s>

Some further discussion with a Rust compiler developer led to [an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/45425) as it doesn't quite seem right. This issue has now been [resolved](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/45435) and should theoretically be available in Rust 1.23.